# Nested isset or session is not working in php

Tags: php, session, get, content-management-system, nested-if

I'm creating a cms and when i go to the specific post page as an admin i want to see edit post link in my navbar.

Session or nested isset is not working please check the code.

Login is working fine i can go to the admin page when i logged in.

php tags already in used just i added the piece of codes.

Login.php

```
if($username !== $db_username && $password !== $db_user_password) {

header("Location: ../index.php");

} else if ($username == $db_username && $password == $db_user_password) {

$_SESSION['username'] = $db_username;
$_SESSION['firstname'] = $db_user_firstname;
$_SESSION['lastname'] = $db_user_lastname;
$_SESSION['user_role'] = $db_user_role;



header("Location: ../admin");
}
```

Navbar.php

```
                if(isset($_SESSION['user_role'])) {

                    if(isset($_GET['p_id'])) {

                        $the_post_id = $_GET['p_id'];   //specific post page 

                        echo "<li><a href='admin/post.php?source=edit_post&p_id={$the_post_id}'>Edit Post</a></li>";

                    }
                    
                }
```

example specific post url is:

localhost/cms/post.php?p_id=14

Comment: Do you have `session_start();` at the beginning of both scripts?

Comment: I had added in the Login.php now i added in the navbar.php and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: `"...&p_id={$the_post_id}..."'` to `"...&p_id=".((int)$the_post_id)."..."'` pls. (Prevent secruity holes)

Comment: Do not check password strings against password strings. Use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` (look those up on php.net) pls.